# jQuery/Ajax loading and displaying content from a window side

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a jQuery script to load content via Ajax (without reloading the page) with two requirements:

- I need to change the URL for each content
- I'd like to load the content with some kind of effect or transition

The effect I'm looking for is working on [this page](http://www.themealings.com.au/) (click on the logo, scroll down the page and then click on the left/right arrow: the content appears from a side and the URL changed!)

I searched a long time for something like this but I had no result :(

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For the first point you could use `history.pushState(null, 'new title', 'new URL').
Here is [the compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)

For the second point, using jquery, you could do:

```
$.ajax(
    url:'your/path/to/the/new/page',
    success:function(data){
        $('body').animate({'left':'-'+window.width}, 'slow', function(){
            document.write(data)
        });

    }
```

)

The body should have a `position: relative;`

This is non-tested prototype

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned ( http://www.themealings.com.au/ ) uses jquery mobile to do the job. With jquery mobile you can automatically ajaxify links, can do history management and animate pages.